# Keyboard bugs (some keys doing strange stuffs)

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac, bug

Since this morning the keyboard is exhibiting some strange behavior:

- "!" key is adding a "@" after the "!"
- "i" key is adding a tab after the "i"
- "k" key is toggling the caps lock after the "k"
- "." key is adding a ">" after the "."

and reciprocally:

- "@" key is adding a "!" before the "@"
- tab key is adding a "i" before the tab
- toggling the caps lock is adding a "k"
- ">" key is adding a "." before the ">"

I'm using OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion on an iMac 27" with an Apple USB French keyboard with the numeric pad (see image below).

I saw this [article on resetting the keyboard](http://www.raneri.it/blog/eng/2009/01/17/how-to-reset-the-mac-keyboard/) but I don't find `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` on my Mac.

Any idea on what I should do?

[image: Apple USB French keyboard]

Comment: Have you tried connecting another keyboard to see if it's a hardware issue?

Comment: Sure sounds like you may need a new keyboard to me.  Try another one as suggested by grgarside.  It doesn't matter if you never spilled anything on it, sometimes they just go.

Comment: i tried with another keyboard and yes, it's working ! strange thing: i went to bed and everything was fine. The next day, for now reason, this keyboard started to bug…